# JOIN ON clause with CASE statement depending on if field is NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a simple LEFT JOIN with tables with 2 IDs - basically an ID and Sub-ID.  Each row has an ID, but not necessarily a Sub-ID.  When a Sub-ID exists, I want to join based on that, if not join on the ID.  I'd imagine something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM tablename a
LEFT JOIN tablename b
 ON CASE WHEN SUB_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
  a.SUB_ID = b.SUB_ID
 ELSE
  a.ID = b.ID END
AND 
  a.otherfield = b.otherfield
```

But I couldn't get anything like this to work, so instead I had to do 2 queries with a UNION (one that joined on SUB_ID WHERE SUB_ID IS NOT NULL and another that joined on ID WHERE SUB_ID IS NULL.)  It worked but I can't imagine there isn't a way to do it.  If it helps, my  ID and SUB_ID values look like this:

```
ID           SUB_ID
10000        NULL
10001        NULL 
10001        10001-3
10001        10001-5
10014        NULL
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this without doing a UNION?  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `COALESCE` for this purpose:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tablename a
LEFT JOIN tablename b
ON COALESCE(a.SUB_ID,a.ID) = COALESCE(b.SUB_ID,b.ID)
```

`COALESCE` returns value of first not null parameter from left.

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff75a9/2)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT ...
FROM tablename a
    LEFT JOIN tablename b
        ON ((b.SUB_ID IS NOT NULL AND a.SUB_ID = b.SUB_ID) OR 
            (a.ID = b.ID))
        AND a.otherfield = b.otherfield
```

Answer (score 0):

You could JOIN the table twice:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tablename a
    LEFT JOIN tablename b
        ON a.SUB_ID = b.SUB_ID
        AND a.otherfield = b.otherfield
    LEFT JOIN tablename c
        ON a.ID = b.ID
        AND a.SUB_ID IS NULL
        AND a.otherfield = c.otherfield
```

Then use `ISNULL` to get the columns, e.g.

```
ColumnName = ISNULL(b.ColumnName, c.ColumnName)
```

It depends on your indexes, but I suspect this may get optimised better than having a conditional join clause.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM tablename a
    LEFT JOIN tablename b
       ON (
         a.SUB_ID = b.SUB_ID
         OR (a.SUB_ID IS NULL AND b.SUB_ID IS NULL AND a.ID = b.ID)
       )
       AND a.otherfield = b.otherfield
```

That might well work.  It's NOT going to be fast, though.

Depending on the state of your data and what you want to achieve, you might want to change the join clause to

```
       ON (
             a.SUB_ID = b.SUB_ID
         OR (a.SUB_ID IS NULL AND a.ID = b.ID)
         OR (b.SUB_ID IS NULL AND a.ID = b.ID)
       )
       AND a.otherfield = b.otherfield
```

... instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME A
LEFT JOIN TABLENAME B
    ON (A.SUB_ID IS NOT NULL AND A.SUB_ID = B.SUB_ID)
    OR (A.SUB_ID IS NULL AND A.ID = B.ID)
```